# Avoid redundancy in a database for a tournament software?

Tags: mysql

I'm about to write a tournament software. Therefor I have two db-tables in mysql database:
`players` and `matches`.
In `matches` I save every single match played in the tournament:

```
ID_player1, ID_player2, Goals_player1, Goals_player2
```

I would like to sum up all goals from all matches of every player, so I can display a ranking, where won mathes and goals and countergoals are displayed. Now the question is, how to realize this in the database: I see several options:

- Save goals and countergoals in the `players` table. Every time a match is entered into the database, the goals and countergoals are added to the related player. (but what about redundancy..?)
- Save goals and countergoals in the `players` table. But every time a match is entered into the database, run a query over the `matches` database and sum up all the goals every time again and again. This way I would at least avoid possible inconsistency.
- Don't save goals and countergoals in `players` table. But every time I would like to display the players rank with all goals and so, there would be a humangous database query running over the whole `matches` table for every single player. This is probably not very smart when it comes to performance, is it?

So what is the best way to store that information..?
I appreciate every help or hint.
greets and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always have a tradeoff between performance and redundancy.

If your database is going to be **really big** and you will need to show each players stats (goals and countergoals) **really often** (like next to his name every time it appears) you should use the option 1. In addition if matches are not played really often you could use the `matches` table to recalculate the stats in order to avoid inconsistency. If they are played really often you will have to just add the new goals and countergoals. This could lead to inconsistency, but again, there will be a tradeoff somewhere.

If the database is not that big or you won't be displaying the stats really often you should stick with option 3 that is the simplest and it won't lead to inconsistency or redundancy.

So, in order to decide which way to go ask yourself:

1. Is the database going to become really huge?
2. Will I need to show the stats really often?
3. Are matches going to be played really often?

With that answers you will need to choose where to priorize performance or redundancy.

Comment: this is my first suggestion. but my concerns with that option is, that it could lead to inconsistency if some failure would occur..

Comment: You're right. I completed change my answer in order to give you some recomendations.

Comment: None of the OP's options are a decent relational model.  And especially if the data is going to get big and queried often, this calls for a proper relational database which does not have to be constantly updated just to keep information consistent from one table to another.  A tradeoff between consistency and performance is not necessary if you use a proper relational model in a database like Mysql which was designed for it.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that goals do not belong to players or to matches.  They belong to the relationship in between.  You need a table that associates a player with a match, call it PlayerPlayedInMatch.  This table would have a player_id and a match_id, that identifies that a particular player played in that match.  And part of the data for that player playing in that match would be the goals they made.

To sum up:

```
PLAYER TABLE
id  (this is primary key)
first_name
last_name
current_ranking
....

MATCH TABLE
id (this is primary key)
Start (date and time match starts)
Location
....

PLAYER_PLAYED_IN_MATCH
player_id (foreign key to player.id)
match_id (foreign key to match.id)
    (player_id and match_id, together, make the primary key of this table)
goals_made
....
```

To query for a total of goals for each players, you would query like this:

```
select player.id, player.name, sum(player_played_in_match.goals_made)
  from player
  join player_played_in_match on player_played_in_match.player_id = player.id
```

To query for goals for each player, listing the matches:

```
select player.id, player.name, match.location, player_played_in_match.goals_made
  from player
  join player_played_in_match on player_played_in_match.player_id = player.id
  join match on player_played_in_match.match_id = match.id
```

You will probably also have a table identifying each team.  There will be similar need to establish the right relationship between your players, teams and matches, and that could get a little complicated if you take into account that a player might move from one team to another so your database might have to account for that.  But it is all doable.

Comment: Thank you for your answere! But if I want to create that ranking-website I have to make as many queries as players in the db over the PlayerPlayedInMatch to get the amount of goals shot by every player..?

Comment: No, this is a basic relational database model.  You can query it for one or multiple players at the same time.  However you want.  I will add a query to give you a list of players with a total of goals, in my answer.